# Java - Yes/No Loop

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("\nWould you like to order some coffee, " + customerName + "? (y/n)");

char response = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
while (response != 'y' && response != 'n') {
  System.out.println("\nInvalid response. Try again.");
  response = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
} if (response == 'n') {
  System.out.println("\nCome back next time, " + customerName + ".");
} else if (response == 'y') {
  System.out.println("\nGreat! Let's get started.");
```

When I run this program and check to see which inputs work, I find that even when I type words starting with 'y' or 'n' the code does not output the error message but moves onto the rest of the program. Also, even if I type in 'Y' or 'N', it registers as an invalid response.

Comment: My first reflex was to reformat the code in the question, but then I realized, that it's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only checks the first character of the input, so it's no wonder words starting with `y` or `n` are considered valid. You might want to compare the entire String :

```
String response = keyboard.next();
while (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
  System.out.println("\nInvalid response. Try again.");
  response = keyboard.next();
} 
if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
  System.out.println("\nCome back next time, " + customerName + ".");
} else {
  System.out.println("\nGreat! Let's get started.");
}
```

Comment: Thank You soooo much that saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are checking only the first letter of the read string:

> char response = keyboard.next().charAt(0)

You should read the whole string:

> String response = keyboard.next()

And use it in the comparison. In order to ensure that also 'Y' and 'N' are considered valid, you can use the [String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-):

> while (!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(response) && "N".equalsIgnoreCase(response))

```
System.out.println("\nWould you like to order some coffee, " + customerName + "? (y/n)");
```

So, wrapping all together this would look like this:

```
String response = keyboard.next();

while (!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(response) && "N".equalsIgnoreCase(response)) {
   System.out.println("\nInvalid response. Try again.");
   response = keyboard.next();
} 

if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(response)) {
   System.out.println("\nCome back next time, " + customerName + ".");
} else if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(response)) {
   System.out.println("\nGreat! Let's get started.");
}
```